# Redirect all traffic from one domain to another one sharing the same IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have domain1 and domain2 sharing the same IP. 
I need to 301 redirect all traffic from domain2 to domain1, including internal pages.

This code works, but only for the homepage. Internal pages are not redirecting:

```
# Redirect Traffic from old domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This other version also works, but again, only for the homepage, not for internal URLs

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd like to know how to make any of these work for internal pages also.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do these sites share the same content?

Comment: Yes. Both share the same content.